# Python , как реализовать отложенный запуск функции для телеграм бота , развернутого на Heroku?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, heroku

Написал функцию, которая отправляет пользователям в определенное время сообщения:

```
def send_wishes_loop(bot, morning_wishes, night_wishes, quotes):
    while True:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(...)

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour  

    cursor.execute("""SELECT userid 
                      FROM usersdata 
                      WHERE morning_time={}""".format(hour))

    for userid in cursor:
        if userid:
            bot.send_message(userid[0] , random.choices(wishes_list.good_morning_wishes))

    .....
    .....

    cursor.close() 
    connection.commit()   
    time.sleep((61 - int(datetime.datetime.now().minute))*60)
```

и добавил ее в отдельный поток

```
t2 = Thread(target=send_wishes_loop,args=(bot, wishes_list.good_morning_wishes, wishes_list.good_night_wishes, wishes_list.quotes))
t2.start()
```

но при загрузке бота на Heroku , в журнале появляется такое сообщение: Stoppind all processes with SIGTERM . Поискал информацию об этой ошибке, вычитал, что Heroku останавливает функции после 30 минутной паузы, а у меня пауза было чуть больше часа. Поменяв время паузы на минуту ,ничего не изменилось. Как исправить эту ошибку? И какие еще есть способы реализации этой функции?

Comment: Procfile покажите

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, bot: python3 tmBot.py